# Subversion Edge Java WrapperManager error on Centos 6

Tags: svn, jvm, java, subversion-edge

I just installed a fresh CentOS 6.3 and now trying to run CollabNet Subversion Edge 3.2.2. 
As of readme I extracted the sources with a user account (owner is now the user and not 7nnn like extracting as root).

For Java i have installed java-1.6.0-openjdk

bin/csvn install
- worked smoothly
bin/csvn console
- brings this:

```
[root@svn-dev-co6 csvn]# bin/csvn console  
Running CSVN Console...  
wrapper  | --> Wrapper Started as Console  
wrapper  | Java Service Wrapper Community Edition 32-bit 3.4.1  
wrapper  |   Copyright (C) 1999-2010 Tanuki Software, Ltd.  All Rights Reserved.  
wrapper  |     http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.org  
wrapper  |  
wrapper  | Command[0] : /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.0/jre/bin/java  
wrapper  | Command[1] : -XX:MaxPermSize=128m  
wrapper  | Command[2] : -Djetty.home=../appserver  
wrapper  | Command[3] : -Djetty.port=3343  
wrapper  | Command[4] : -Djetty.ssl.port=4434  
wrapper  | Command[5] : -Xms64m  
wrapper  | Command[6] : -Xmx512m  
wrapper  | Command[7] : -Djava.library.path=../lib  
wrapper  | Command[8] : -classpath  
wrapper  | Command[9] : ../lib/wrapper.jar  
wrapper  | Command[10] : -Dwrapper.key=TOmk3EllD5MzqPTW  
wrapper  | Command[11] : -Dwrapper.port=32000  
wrapper  | Command[12] : -Dwrapper.jvm.port.min=31000  
wrapper  | Command[13] : -Dwrapper.jvm.port.max=31999  
wrapper  | Command[14] : -Dwrapper.pid=16065  
wrapper  | Command[15] : -Dwrapper.version=3.4.1  
wrapper  | Command[16] : -Dwrapper.native_library=wrapper  
wrapper  | Command[17] : -Dwrapper.cpu.timeout=10  
wrapper  | Command[18] : -Dwrapper.jvmid=1  
wrapper  | Command[19] : org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperJarApp  
wrapper  | Command[20] : ../appserver/start.jar  
wrapper  | Launching a JVM...  
jvm 1    | WrapperManager: Initializing...  
jvm 1    | WrapperManager Error: Failed to connect to the Wrapper at port 32000.    Cause:     java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused  
jvm 1    | WrapperManager Error: Exiting JVM...  
wrapper  | JVM exited while loading the application.
```

Testing the java binary + variable:

```
sh-4.1$ /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.0/jre/bin/java -version
java version "1.6.0_24"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.11.5) (rhel-1.50.1.11.5.el6_3-i386)
OpenJDK Client VM (build 20.0-b12, mixed mode)
sh-4.1$ $JAVA_HOME
sh: /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.0/jre: ist ein Verzeichnis.
sh-4.1$ $JAVA_HOME/bin/java -version
java version "1.6.0_24"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.11.5) (rhel-1.50.1.11.5.el6_3-i386)
OpenJDK Client VM (build 20.0-b12, mixed mode)
```

Any suggestions or hints to find out, why the Wrapper/JVM isn't starting up?

data/logs/ is empty
Setting csvn-wrapper.conf loglevel to debug did not change anything than even shorter output (no commands anymore).

Thanks, Max

Answer (score 0):

I have not seen that, but fwiw I have only used the Sun/Oracle 1.6 JVM on Linux.  I have successfully used OpenJDK 7.

Just for your peace of mind, note that csvn install only copies the start scripts to /etc/init.d.  Nothing else really.

The "wrapper" is Java Service Wrapper as noted in the beginning of the output.  Perhaps their community forums have some answers.